# Add description in Shopify Collection

Tags: shopify

I am trying to add a description to each image in a collection in Shopify in the featured-collection.liquid snippet.
In the code below on the bottom, there is the line for the title, so I figured I could put one in for description, which can be added in the shopify backend.
I have taken the code from the  and changed it to description.

like this:

Can anybody tell me what I should change, because now it isn't working yet.

Thanks
Jakob

```html
{% unless featured_collection_width %}
  {% assign featured_collection_width = 'small--one-half medium--one-third large--one-sixth' %}
{% endunless %}

{% unless featured_collection_size %}
  {% assign featured_collection_size = '540x' %}
{% endunless %}

{% if collections[featured].image %}
  {% assign collection_image = collections[featured].image %}
{% else %}
  {% assign collection_image = collections[featured].products.first.featured_image %}
{% endif %}

<div class="grid-item {{ featured_collection_width }}">
  {% capture collection_title %}{{ collections[featured].title | escape }}{% endcapture %}
  <a href="{{ collections[featured].url }}" title="{{ 'collections.general.link_title' | t: title: collection_title }}" class="featured-box">
    <div class="featured-box--inner" >
      <div class="featured-box--image {% unless collection_image == blank %} vertical-middle{% endunless %}">
        {% if featured != blank %}
          {% if collections[featured].image or collections[featured].products.first.featured_image %}
            {% capture img_id %}collectionFeaturedImage-{{ section.id }}--{{ collection_image.id }}{% endcapture %}
            {% capture img_id_class %}collectionImage--{{ collection_image.id }}{% endcapture %}
            {% capture wrapper_id %}collectionImageWrapper-{{ collection_image.id }}{% endcapture %}
            {%- assign img_url = collection_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}
            {% unless collection_image == blank %}
              {% include 'image-style' with image: collection_image, width: width, height: height, small_style: false, wrapper_id: wrapper_id, img_id_class: img_id_class %}
            {% endunless %}
            <div id="{{ wrapper_id }}" class="lazyload__image-wrapper no-js">
              <div {% if collection_image != blank %}style="padding-top:{{ 1 | divided_by: collection_image.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%;"{% endif %}>
                <img id="{{ img_id }}"
                  class="no-js lazyload {{ img_id_class }}"
                  data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                  data-widths="[125, 180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
                  data-aspectratio="{{ collection_image.aspect_ratio }}"
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  alt="{{ collection_image.alt | escape }}">
              </div>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
            {{ 'collection-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
          {{ 'collection-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      {% unless collection_image == blank %}
      <noscript>
        <img src="{{ collection_image | img_url: '580x' }}"
          srcset="{{ collection_image | img_url: '580x' }} 1x, {{ collection_image | img_url: '580x', scale: 2 }} 2x"
          alt="{{ collection_image.alt }}" style="opacity:1;">
      </noscript>
      {% endunless %}
    </div>
    <span class="featured-box--title">{% if collection_title != blank %}{{ collection_title }}{% else %}{{ 'homepage.featured_collection_rows.heading' | t }}{% endif %}</span>
    
    
    
    
    <span class="featured-box--description">{% if collection_description != blank %}{{ collection_description }}{% else %}{{ 'homepage.featured_collection_rows.heading' | t }}{% endif %}</span>
    

    
    
    
    
  </a>
</div>
```

This is what I am getting as of now:
[my collection on shopify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS4TS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are including collection_description but you haven't defined it.

Look at the code for collection_image near the top of your snippet.

At some point you would make use of something like:

```
{% assign collection_description = collections[featured].description %}
```